# Proof of $ e^x-x^2 \gt 1 $ when $ x \gt 0$ and $x$ is a real number .

Tags: convergence-divergence, exponential-function

I want to Prove  $ e^x-x^2 \gt 1 $ when $ x \gt 0$ and $x$ is a real number . For this purpose , my trying is as the following :

$ e^x-x^2 = \{1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2!} + +\dfrac{x^3}{3!}++\dfrac{x^4}{4!}+ ....... \}-x^2$
           $= 1+\{x-\dfrac{x^2}{2!} + +\dfrac{x^3}{3!}++\dfrac{x^4}{4!}+ ....... \}$

So $ e^x-x^2 \gt 1 $ is true if $\{x-\dfrac{x^2}{2!} + +\dfrac{x^3}{3!}++\dfrac{x^4}{4!}+ ....... \} \ge $ Please help me finding the convergence of this term .

Comment: Simpler: differentiate the difference twice and deduce that the derivative is minimum on $x\geqslant0$ at $x=\log2$, where it is positive, hence the difference is positive for every $x\gt0$.

Answer (score 2):

The second derivative of $e^x-x^2-1$ gives you the inflection point at $x = ln(2)$.
The problem is equivalent to $e^{ln(2)}-len(2)^2>1$ or $1>ln(2)$, wich is true

Comment: If I want to prove this by finding convergence of this term $\{x-\dfrac{x^2}{2!} + +\dfrac{x^3}{3!}++\dfrac{x^4}{4!}+ ....... \} \ge 0$ then what can I do ?

Comment: The convergence is $e^x-x^2-1$, nothing else.

What you can do is study $x-x^2/2+x^3/6$, which is positive for $x>0$